# flask MethodView with decorators is giving error

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I'm trying to use `flask-security-too` `auth_required` with flask's `MethodView` as described under https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/views/#decorating-views, and exception is being raised when I try to access the page. python 3.6.8

```
from flask_security import auth_required

class RunningRoutesAdmin(MethodView):
    decorators = [auth_required]

    def get(self):
        return render_template('admin.jinja2',
                               pagename='Admin Home')

admin_view = RunningRoutesAdmin.as_view('admin')
app.add_url_rule('/admin/', view_func=admin_view, methods=['GET',])
```

exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lking\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\runningroutes\runningroutes\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\lking\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\runningroutes\runningroutes\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\lking\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\runningroutes\runningroutes\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\lking\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\runningroutes\runningroutes\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\lking\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\runningroutes\runningroutes\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\lking\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\runningroutes\runningroutes\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\lking\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\runningroutes\runningroutes\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\lking\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\runningroutes\runningroutes\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\lking\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\runningroutes\runningroutes\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\lking\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\runningroutes\runningroutes\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fn'
```

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything wrong. I just repro'd it. The issue is that @auth_required is a 'double wrapped' decorator. I am trying to figure out a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - simple solution - since auth_required takes parameters - you need to:

```
decorators = [auth_required()]
```

Sorry - I suggested passing in None - which of course isn't correct. Passing in nothing or a list of acceptable methods (e.g. "session", "token") works fine.

Comment: Hmm, with this change it seems to always send me to the login page, even when I'm logged in. And even after I relog in I am sent back back to the login page with url http://dev.localhost:5000/admin/login?next=%2Fadmin%2F

Comment: Just noticed your update -- passing in nothing works fine. Not exactly sure what you mean by a list of acceptable methods. You mean like "get", a string for a ```MethodView``` method? Or ```get``` the method itself?

Comment: Should I write an issue in ```flask-security-too``` to clarify decorator use with ```MethodView```?

Comment: As documented here: https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_security.auth_required. auth_required decorator takes a list of allowable auth_methods (as in "session", "token"). While it confused me as well - this is basic python decorator usage - if the decorator takes an argument (and not just the implicit function to wrap) - then you need to pass those arguments in - same as if you did this in line: auth_required("session")(-my-func-)

Comment: Oh, auth methods as opposed to class methods. Got it. Thanks again!